# indexPath.row gives weird values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am displaying `indexPath.row` number as custom `UILabel` also defined in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That label is added as a subview of that custom cell. When I have lots of cells and swipe down the tableview, that `indexPath.row` numbers have weird values and if I scroll more, values are hgher. How can I bypass this?

[EDIT] my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SKSTableViewCell";

    self.sksTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!self.sksTableViewCell)
        self.sksTableViewCell = [[SKSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    self.sksTableViewCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[[[ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]];
    self.sksTableViewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ([[[[ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] times] count]) {
        self.sksTableViewCell.expandable = YES;
    } else {
        self.sksTableViewCell.expandable = NO;
    }

    // UIButton for directly switching racers
    UIButton *stopwatchIcon = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [stopwatchIcon addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedButtonToGoToTheRacerDirectly:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stopwatch"];
    stopwatchIcon.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-70, 27.5-img.size.height/2, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    [stopwatchIcon setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    stopwatchIcon.tag = [[self.indexDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]]] intValue];
    [self.sksTableViewCell addSubview:stopwatchIcon];

    // Medals
    int golds = [[self.bestThreeRacersDictionary objectForKey:@"golds"] intValue];
    int silvers = [[self.bestThreeRacersDictionary objectForKey:@"silvers"] intValue];
    int bronzes = [[self.bestThreeRacersDictionary objectForKey:@"bronzes"] intValue];

    // Medal image and view
    UIImage *medalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"medal"];
    UIImageView *medalImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stopwatchIcon.frame.origin.x-medalImage.size.width-7.5, 27.5-medalImage.size.height/2, medalImage.size.width, medalImage.size.height)];
    // TextLabel
    UILabel *numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(medalImageView.frame.origin.x+medalImageView.frame.size.width/4, medalImageView.frame.origin.y+medalImageView.frame.size.height/4, medalImageView.frame.size.width/2, medalImageView.frame.size.height/2)];
    numberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    numberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    numberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    numberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    numberLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [Racer shift:golds silvers:silvers bronzes:bronzes]+helpIndex];
    helpIndex++;
    if (indexPath.row < golds) {
        medalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldMedal"];
        numberLabel.text = @"1";
        helpIndex--;
    } else if (indexPath.row < (golds+silvers)) {
        medalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"silverMedal"];
        numberLabel.text = @"2";
        helpIndex--;
    } else if (indexPath.row < (golds+silvers+bronzes)) {
        medalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bronzeMedal"];
        numberLabel.text = @"3";
        helpIndex--;
    }
    medalImageView.image = medalImage;
    medalImageView.tag = 5;
    numberLabel.tag = 5;
    [self.sksTableViewCell addSubview:medalImageView];
    [self.sksTableViewCell addSubview:numberLabel];

    return self.sksTableViewCell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Perhaps you're adding a new label every time `cellForRow` is called? If so, you should not do that

Comment: Why are you using a property to keep a reference to the last cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid creating new UIButtons and UILabels in cellForRow methods. Cells in UITableView are reused, so the objects which disappear from the screen when you scroll are used again to show new rows. And you're adding a new view every time this happens.

Instead you should create all view hierarchy just once and update the views you need to be updated.

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[SKSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //create all your subviews here
}

//update subviews here
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create new object of UI component for every cell just do it once after then cell reuse .